# Como navegar entre FRAGMENT sin perder la información que se tiene en los campos EditText?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo varios FRAGMENT que se visualizan en un activity de uno en uno, en cada FRAGMENT tengo un formulario con campos EditText. El problema que tengo es que cuando lleno los campos EditText de un FRAGMENT y paso al siguiente FRAGMENT y me devuelvo, los datos del FRAGMENT anterior en los EditText desaparecen y queda en blanco, como cuando se inicia la aplicacion.

¿Como hago para navegar entre los FRAGMENT sin que se pierdan los que hay en los EditText?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta sencilla es que el `EdiText` en realidad solo debe estar mostrando la información que está guardada en el `Activity` (o en el `ViewModel` si estas usando `MVVM`). Entonces al cambiar de `Fragment`, aquel que necesite de esa información la puede obtener del `Activity` (o `ViewModel`).

Cuando se hace un cambio en el `EditText`, tienes que actualizar la información en el `Activity` (o `ViewModel`), de esta forma el `EditText` no es mas que un medio para poder modificar el dato, en lugar de ser el lugar de almacenamiento del dato.